# Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually

Tags: android, linux, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run a sample app on my android device with the following command :

```
sudo ionic cordova run android --device
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android --device exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I already set the JAVA_HOME environment variable but that doesn't work .

```
~/Ionic/helloWorld$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk-amd64
```

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the correct location. But the path should have `$JAVA_HOME/bin` directory and not `$JAVA_HOME` itself.

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.12.0"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

You should consider using the Oracle Java PPA instead. It usually does more than what a manual installation would do. You don't have to worry about setting up the environment variables either. That's what most people use.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Try running java -version and `javac -version` to verify that the path is set.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This path is already set : when running java -version and javac -version , I get the message that java 12  is installed

Answer (score 2):

I have debian 10 and i solve this problem installing openjdk 1.8. And then you have to run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

You don't need to set JAVA_HOME because with update-alternatives java and javac are linked to bin.

Comment: Perfect, I missed changing the latter (javac), but with that it now works

Comment: 'sudo: update-alternatives: command not found' getting this error message in console window.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed java OpenJDK you should install the Java SE. You can find your system-specific JDK [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html).

Your JAVA_HOME should look like following

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle (I have java 8 , you can have any version)
```

Comment: I have installed JAVA SE 12 but I don't get java-12-oracle directory , jdk-12.0.2 instead

Comment: I have open-jdk, so mine was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk`, same path tho, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gotten it to work is by declaring the variables in the command itself.

Try it like this:

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/Android/Sdk/ cordova requirements android --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

You’ve Java SDK 12 version which is not set into `JAVA_HOME` environment. You can set this using below command:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.12.0"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

**Tip:** You can search for list of JDK installed on your machine using:
cmd + shift + G and type in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

**Step 2:**

If you get an error *native-run was not found on your PATH* then you need to install globally:

```
npm i -g native-run
```

[image: Screenshot-1]

**Step-3:**

While running above command if you get *permission denied error* then run using super admin privilege:

```
sudo npm i -g native-run
```

[image: Screenshot-2]

**Step-4:**

Now again when you run `sudo ionic cordova run android --device` command you may get error regarding gradle. You can fix this using below command in terminal window:

```
brew install gradle
```

**Tip:** It took me around 10 minutes to install gradle (first time user).

[image: Screenshot-3]

**Step-5:**

Now `sudo ionic cordova run android --device` command should launch you app on android device without any error.