# CordovaError: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, debian

I get a ionic project from a person, and I want to debug it in a real android device.
I use this command:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --verbose
```

And in the end I get these error messages:

> Preparing Firebase on Android
> No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
> Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
> CordovaError: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.

I have `JAVA_HOME` set, indeed if I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

According to [Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356094/failed-to-find-java-home-environment-variable-try-setting-it-manually) post, I also tried adding `bin` folder to `JAVA_HOME` variable, without any success.

If I also try `java -version` and `javac -version` I get success messages.

Comment: Are you running Ionic as a different user by any chance?

Comment: no :( I am checking internet and it seems java 11 is not compatible with linux-android cordova. I should install specifically version 8 of jdk. does it make sense?

Comment: I think it's worth a try.

Comment: yes you should try JDK 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Version 10.0.0 of Cordova requires jdk version 8. That's it.